# Cordova build for iOS in VS2015 fails with "Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build

Figured out a new problem with cordova build for iOS platform:
`Error: Error from downloading build outputs to <path_to_project>\bin\iOS\Debug: Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found`

To reproduce you'll need XCode 8.1 (8B62) on MacOS Sierra 10.12.1. Create new TypeScript\Apache Cordova Apps project in Visual Studio 2015. Configure Cordova remote iOS build settings to compile against the Mac machine with the configuration mentioned above. The cordova version in `config.xml` is configured as 6.1.1. Build the project and you'll see the error that a code signing is required and a team must be supplied.

I used [this solution](https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html) to get over this error but then I received the `Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found` error. When I check the .zip file in the folder provided by the build the file seems like an empty one and could not be opened. Therefore it seems like the XCode doesn't package the build results well.

In case I take the `...\www\platforms\ios` folder from the project structure and open its `.xcodeproj` file in XCode the application compiles and runs without any problem but on Mac and I need it to get compiled via Visual Studio as before.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: As I understood there's just a problem of packaging the .ipa file into zip and then downloading this .zip to Windows machine and extracting it so as a temporary remedy you may do the following:

Comment: There seem to be a problem of packaging the .ipa file into zip and downloading this .zip to Windows machine and extracting it so as a temporary remedy you may do the following:
1. Run the remotebuild on the Mac with --serverDir <something> so the <something> will be a visible folder under your user root folder in Finder.
2. Run the build on VS2015.
3. A folder will be created in Mac: "<something>/taco-remote/builds/<build#>/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device" (also this path is shown in VS2015). There will be located your .ipa that is fully functional.
Still hope for a better solution.